# Google Analytics Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Kinda new to Rgeluar expressions and for the benefit of learning wanted to know how to do the following on one line:

page matching regular expression: .pdf/$

and page containing "somestring"

and page excluding "someotherstring"

I can obtain my desired output using the 3 rules above. My question is can I put all into one line using regular expression? So the first line would be something like:

```
page matching reg exp: .pdf/$ somestring+ (then regex for does not contain in GA) someotherstring
```

Is it possible to put all in a oner?

Comment: Do you really need the slash after `.pdf`?

Comment: I didn't think so either but when testing it I did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will help you to match multiple independent things in one expression, and even allows to require non-matching. In your case:

```
/^(?=.*somestring)(?!.*someotherstring).*\.pdf$/
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot.
Could you help by clarifying:
Why the "^" second character?
What does ?=.* mean in English?! I am googling it but working myself into confusion. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: If you omitted the [start of string anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html), the regex might have matched only a part of your input (depending on the invocation). I already linked a doc for the lookahead expression. In English: It asserts that now follows an arbitrary number of chars and then the word "somestring".

Comment: Lookahead is not fully supported by Google Analytics.

Comment: Hm, I don't know then how to formulate these rules in one line. Especially "does not contain" would be very complicated without negative lookahead.